# Он обвиняет в этом жену?

Tags: падежи, род

> «Когда русскому человеку особенно плохо живется, он обвиняет в этом
>   жену, соседа, погоду, Бога - всех, кроме самого себя.»

1. Этом - prepositional,
   Жену - accusative.
   Why don't they match?
2. Этом - masculine,
   Жена - feminine.
   Why not Этой?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: этом is neuter, not masculine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant part of the phrase translates as "he accuses his wife of this".

*Обвинять* is a polyvalent verb which accepts up to two objects (one direct and one prepositional): *обвинять кого? (acc.) в чём? (prep.)*

Compare English verb "to accuse someone of something".

So those are two different objects and they don't have to agree with each other.

Comment: I now got it. It finally makes perfect sense! :)

Answer (score 2):

В этом => в том, что ему плохо живется. It has nothing to do with the word "жена".

Comment: Большое спасибо!